# Cannot create PDF file in QT 5.1.1

Tags: qt

Hello i cannot create my pdf file. I am using simple code example which i have found on the internet, but there is some error which i dont understand.

```
    #include <QTextDocument>
    #include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter> //My version of Qt doesnt know <QPrinter>


    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QTextDocument file;
    file.setHtml( "<h1> "Example Text" </h1>" );

    QPrinter printer;
    printer.setOutputFileName("example.pdf");
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    file.print(&printer);
    printer.newPage();

}
```

Error:

```
debug/mainwindow.o: In function `ZN10MainWindowC2EP7QWidget':
C:\Users\Jaromír\Documents\Qt\build-PDF_test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../PDF_test/mainwindow.cpp:18: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QPrinterC1ENS_11PrinterModeE'
C:\Users\Jaromír\Documents\Qt\build-PDF_test-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../PDF_test/mainwindow.cpp:19: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8QPrinter17setOutputFileNameERK7QString'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your `.pro` file:

`QT += printsupport`

You can read more about print support [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtprintsupport/qtprintsupport-module.html).

Not strictly related to your question, but you can find more about different modules [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/modules-cpp.html) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtmodules.html), just in case you need it in the future.